# Why do some texts say that noncompetitive antagonist dose no change in ED50 of agonist in Dose-respond curve?

Tags: pharmacology, pharmacodynamics

Competitive antagonists increase the ED50 while the Emax remains the same. Non-competitive antagonists do not change the ED50 while decreases the Emax.

I wonder how does this happen as Non-competitive has no effect on ED50.[image]